# How do you retrieve pod logs by labelSelector when using the k8s HTTP API?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-apiserver

I would like to collect the logs from one or more related pods using a labelSelector and the kubernetes HTTP API. However, I don't see any way to do this without first knowing all the pods names, e.g.

```
{{baseUrl}}/api/v1/namespaces/:namespace/pods/:name/log?container=cillum &follow=true&insecureSkipTLSVerifyBackend=true&limitBytes=-94468552&pretty=cillum &previous=true&sinceSeconds=-94468552&tailLines=-94468552&timestamps=true
```

Is this possible, or should I mount a container with `kubectl` and use that to get the logs I want?

I can get the logs using `kubectl` like so:

```
kubectl logs -l job=myjob -n test -c main
```

I would assume there is a similar way to retrieve logs using the `labelSelector` using the API.

Comment: The answer to any "what api do I use for this kubectl thing?" is `kubectl --v=10 ...` which will show the `curl` equivalent for any action it takes. For your specific question, you'll observe that yes, one always needs the pod names for logs, but that using `-l` with logs merely does `k get po -o name -l ...` and _then_ does `k logs $that_name`; it's the same way `k exec deploy/some-deploy` works, because (obviously) one cannot really exec into a Deployment